# Conversion of (autogenerated?) EJB code from Websphere to Glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb, websphere

I have an existing legacy Java application that is built to run in a Websphere 7.0 environment.  We are moving away from Websphere to Glassfish.  The original developer of this code is not around, and as expected there is no documentation.

The majority of the conversion is simple.  However, the EJB 2.1 code is problematic; the bean definitions themselves are fine, but there is a lot of ancillary code that is very, very tightly coupled with IBM Websphere libraries and does not seem like it will be possible to convert without a total rewrite.

An example:

```
/**
 * MyBeanAdaptorBinding_ebb6f53f
 */
public class MyBeanAdaptorBinding_ebb6f53f implements com.ibm.ws.ejbpersistence.beanextensions.EJBAdapterBinding {
    /**
     * getExtractor
     */
    public com.ibm.ws.ejbpersistence.dataaccess.EJBExtractor getExtractor() {
        // extractor for mypackage.entity.websphere_deploy.ORACLE_V11_1.MyBeanExtractor_ebb6f53f
        com.ibm.ws.ejbpersistence.dataaccess.AbstractEJBExtractor extractor =  new mypackage.entity.websphere_deploy.ORACLE_V11_1.MyBeanExtractor_ebb6f53f();
        extractor.setPrimaryKeyColumns(new int[] {1});
        extractor.setDataColumns(new int[] {1,2});
        return extractor;
    }
    /**
     * getInjector
     */
    public com.ibm.ws.ejbpersistence.beanextensions.EJBInjector getInjector() {
        return new mypackage.entity.websphere_deploy.ORACLE_V11_1.MyBeanInjectorImpl_ebb6f53f();
    }
    /**
     * getAdapter
     */
    public com.ibm.websphere.ejbpersistence.EJBToRAAdapter getAdapter() {
        return com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.cci.WSRelationalRAAdapter.createAdapter();
    }
    /**
     * getMetadata
     */
    public Object[] getMetadata() {

        java.lang.String[] primarykey, subhomes, composedObjs, composedObjImpls;
        com.ibm.ObjectQuery.metadata.OSQLExternalCatalogEntry[] cat;
        com.ibm.ObjectQuery.metadata.OSQLExternalColumnDef[] fields;
        cat = new com.ibm.ObjectQuery.metadata.OSQLExternalCatalogEntry[5];

        //-------------------------------------Alias-------------------------------------
        cat[0] = new com.ibm.ObjectQuery.metadata.OSQLExternalCatalogRDBAlias("My", "My1_Alias", "ORACLE", "MYSCHEMA.My", "My_My1_Table", 11, 0, 0);


        //-----------------------------------Table Type-----------------------------------
        fields = new com.ibm.ObjectQuery.metadata.OSQLExternalColumnDef[2];

        fields[0] = new com.ibm.ObjectQuery.metadata.OSQLExternalColumnDef("MyID", new String(), com.ibm.ObjectQuery.engine.OSQLConstants.NOT_APPLICABLE, new String(), com.ibm.ObjectQuery.engine.OSQLConstants.NOT_APPLICABLE, true, com.ibm.ObjectQuery.engine.OSQLSymbols._CHARACTER, 250, com.ibm.ObjectQuery.engine.OSQLConstants.NO_TYPE, true, 0, -1, 0, false);
        fields[1] = new com.ibm.ObjectQuery.metadata.OSQLExternalColumnDef("MyNM", new String(), com.ibm.ObjectQuery.engine.OSQLConstants.NOT_APPLICABLE, new String(), com.ibm.ObjectQuery.engine.OSQLConstants.NOT_APPLICABLE, true, com.ibm.ObjectQuery.engine.OSQLSymbols._CHARACTER, 250, com.ibm.ObjectQuery.engine.OSQLConstants.NO_TYPE, false, 0, -1, 0, false);
        primarykey = new String[1];
        primarykey[0] = "MyID";
        cat[1] = new com.ibm.ObjectQuery.metadata.OSQLExternalCatalogType("My", "My1_Table", null, fields, primarykey);


        //-----------------------------------Bean Type-----------------------------------
        fields = new com.ibm.ObjectQuery.metadata.OSQLExternalColumnDef[2];

        fields[0] = new com.ibm.ObjectQuery.metadata.OSQLExternalColumnDef("MyId", new String(), com.ibm.ObjectQuery.engine.OSQLConstants.NOT_APPLICABLE, new String(), com.ibm.ObjectQuery.engine.OSQLConstants.NOT_APPLICABLE, true, com.ibm.ObjectQuery.engine.OSQLSymbols._CHARACTER, 0, com.ibm.ObjectQuery.engine.OSQLConstants.NO_TYPE, false, 0, -1, 0, false);
        fields[1] = new com.ibm.ObjectQuery.metadata.OSQLExternalColumnDef("MyNm", new String(), com.ibm.ObjectQuery.engine.OSQLConstants.NOT_APPLICABLE, new String(), com.ibm.ObjectQuery.engine.OSQLConstants.NOT_APPLICABLE, true, com.ibm.ObjectQuery.engine.OSQLSymbols._CHARACTER, 0, com.ibm.ObjectQuery.engine.OSQLConstants.NO_TYPE, false, 0, -1, 0, false);
        primarykey = new String[1];
        primarykey[0] = "MyId";
        cat[2] = new com.ibm.ObjectQuery.metadata.OSQLExternalCatalogType("My", "My_BO", "mypackage.entity.MyBean", fields, primarykey);


        //--------------------------------------View--------------------------------------
        composedObjs = null;
        composedObjImpls = null;
        subhomes = null;
        cat[3] = new com.ibm.ObjectQuery.metadata.OSQLExternalCatalogView("My", "My_My_BO", "My_My1_Alias", composedObjs, composedObjImpls, 
        "select t1.MyID,t1.MyNM from _this t1", 
        null, subhomes, 
        0, null);



        cat[4] = new com.ibm.ObjectQuery.metadata.OSQLExternalSysApplOptions(14, false);

        return cat;
    }
    /**
     * createDataAccessSpecs
     */
    public java.util.Collection createDataAccessSpecs() throws javax.resource.ResourceException {
        <snipped long implementation of find/create/delete logic using com.ibm.ws.* classes>
    }
    /**
     * getProperties
     */
    public java.util.HashMap getProperties() {
        properties.put("USING_DB_AUTO_OCC_COLLISION_DETECTION", Boolean.FALSE);
        properties.put("NEED_REFRESH_AFTER_PERSISTENCE", Boolean.FALSE);
        return properties;
    }
    /**
     * MyBeanAdaptorBinding_ebb6f53f
     */
    public MyBeanAdaptorBinding_ebb6f53f() {
        properties = new java.util.HashMap();
        properties.put("VERSION", "7.0.0.0");
    }
    private java.util.HashMap properties;
}
```

This code (and much of the rest) seems autogenerated: the _ebb6f53f suffix, the fully specified classnames, etc.  Going along with this is also MyBeanCacheEntry_ebb6f53f, MyBeanExtractor_ebb6f53f, MyBeanFunctionSet_ebb6f53f, MyBeanInjector_ebb6f53f, and MyBeanInternalHome_ebb6f53f (plus relevant implementations for the ones that are interfaces).  Every bean's set of ancillary classes has a different hex string suffix.

The relevant section of the ejb-jar.xml file:

```
    <entity id="My">
        <ejb-name>My</ejb-name>
        <local-home>mypackage.entity.MyLocalHome</local-home>
        <local>mypackage.entity.MyLocal</local>
        <ejb-class>mypackage.entity.MyBean</ejb-class>
        <persistence-type>Container</persistence-type>
        <prim-key-class>java.lang.String</prim-key-class>
        <reentrant>false</reentrant>
        <cmp-version>2.x</cmp-version>
        <abstract-schema-name>My</abstract-schema-name>
        <cmp-field id="CMPAttribute_1133536288497">
            <field-name>MyId</field-name>
        </cmp-field>
        <cmp-field id="CMPAttribute_1133536292665">
            <field-name>MyNm</field-name>
        </cmp-field>
        <primkey-field>MyId</primkey-field>
    </entity>
```

The cmp-field ids are taken from an Oracle Map.mapxmi file.  Neither ejb-jar.xml nor Map.mapxmi seem tied to Websphere so I do not believe they require modification, but if they *did* I would assume that they are autogenerated as well.

This is not a maven or ant project; the build procedure is done directly through Eclipse and does not modify/autogenerate code as part of the build; it just compiles the JAR and then packages the WAR and EAR.

I am not very knowledgeable about EJBs or Websphere.  I have done a lot of searching and reading over the last few days, but have been unable to satisfactorily answer the following questions:

1. How was this code generated (Eclipse or Rational Application Developer tool, specific Websphere tool, etc)?
2. How would the ejb-jar.xml and Map.mapxmi file have been generated?
3. Is it possible to be regenerated for Glassfish without the com.ibm.* dependencies (preferably only with javax.* dependencies)?
4. Is this type of code even required for a non-Websphere deployment?

Comment: You will need to migrate the EJB 2.1 CMP entity beans to JPA. You might get CMP up and running in Glassfish but it will be difficult. You should be able to throw away the generated code as different Java EE implementations create this functionality in their own way.

Comment: @SteveC You're right that all of the autogenerated code was simply deletable, so that was helpful.  If you create it as an answer I'll happily mark it as correct.